# How to use a custom excel function (or add-in) in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, excel, add-in, vba

Is there a way I can reuse a set of custom functions originally written in Excel 2010 in Access2010? I am writing an excel add-in which provides custom functions to the excel users. Some of these functions refer to data in one of the excel sheets.The same functionality is also required in one of the access DBs as well.

I am new to the excel world and just wondering if this can be done?

(I've been a java coder for a long time and recently started to work on excel)

Update: 
In response to Tim's comment - For the moment I dont have only "simple" conditions and code, but you're right that may change as complexity grows. Sample function:

```
Function BaselinedNumber(baseline_high, baseline_low, high)
    If baseline_low = 0 Then
        BaselinedNumber = 0
    Else
        baseDiscount = (baseline_high - baseline_low) / baseline_high
        BaselinedNumber = high * (1 - baseDiscount)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Whether you can use them in Access depends on exactly what they do.  Seems unlikely you could use them without *any* modification unless they are user-defined functions which take only parameter types which VBA in Access can deal with (e.g. no `Range` parameters).  If you show some actual code you may get more specific advice.

Comment: It also depend on what "use them in Acces" means. Do you want to use them against a table in Access or are you automating Excel from Access?

Comment: @Remou - What I'm hoping to do is to add-in these functions to an access DB and call them in queries etc.

Comment: I see no reason why you should not call that particular function in Access.

Comment: I do want to call that function in  - the question is how do you do it? Create a COM addi-in? the excel add-in refuses to import

Answer (score -1):

Dim appExcel As New Excel.Application

appExcel.Visible = False

appExcel.Workbooks.Open excelFileName

appExcel.Run (BaselinedNumber), val1, val2, val3

appExcel.Quit